# Get imports from a PEFile in C?

Tags: c

Most of the examples on the web on how to get imports from a pefile is by directly feeding the filepath to CreateFile. But in my case, I already have map of the file using MapViewOfFile in memory with a pointer to start and end of the pefile. Due to the size of my code, I unfortunately cannot provide all the code, but hopefully below is reproducible.

```
int assumeMain(){
    PVOID startAddress;

    HANDLE   secHdl = NULL;
    startAddress= MapViewOfFile( secHdl,
        FILE_MAP_READ, // originally was FILE_MAP_READ
                             0L,
                             0L,
                             0 );
    if (startAddress== NULL){
        // do stuff
    }
    anPefile((unsigned char*)startAddress), size);
}

int anPefile(_In_reads_bytes_(Size)    PUCHAR   StartingAddress,
    _In_                      SIZE_T   Size,){
    PUCHAR start = StartingAddress;
    PUCHAR end = start + Size;

    getImports(start, end);
}

int getImports(PUCHAR start, PUCHAR end) {
    DWORD base = (DWORD)start;
    DWORD size = (DWORD)end - (DWORD)start;


    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER fileHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)start;
    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS fileNTHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((BYTE*)fileHeader + fileHeader->e_lfanew);

    DWORD resourceVirtualAddress = fileNTHeader->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_RESOURCE].VirtualAddress;
    if (resourceVirtualAddress == 0) {
        printf("No resource directory found in the PE file\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    DumpImportsSection(base, fileNTHeader);
    return filerank;
}

// This function is from pedump project.
void DumpImportsSection(DWORD base, PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pNTHeader)
{
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR importDesc;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSection;
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA thunk, thunkIAT = 0;
    PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME pOrdinalName;
    DWORD importsStartRVA;
    PSTR pszTimeDate;

    // Look up where the imports section is (normally in the .idata section)
    // but not necessarily so.  Therefore, grab the RVA from the data dir.
    importsStartRVA = GetImgDirEntryRVA(pNTHeader, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT);
    if (!importsStartRVA)
        return;
    printf("importsStartRVA: %d\n", importsStartRVA);
    // Get the IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER that contains the imports.  This is
    // usually the .idata section, but doesn't have to be.
    pSection = GetEnclosingSectionHeader(importsStartRVA, pNTHeader);
    if (!pSection)
        return;

    importDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)
        GetPtrFromRVA(importsStartRVA, pNTHeader, base);
    if (!importDesc)
        return;

    printf("Imports Table: \n");

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Before importing\n");
        printf("Name: %p\n", &importDesc);
        // See if we've reached an empty IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
        if ((importDesc->TimeDateStamp == 0) && (importDesc->Name == 0))
            break;
        printf("After importing\n");
        printf("  %s\n", GetPtrFromRVA(importDesc->Name, pNTHeader, base));

        printf("  OrigFirstThunk:  %08X (Unbound IAT)\n",
            importDesc->Characteristics);

        pszTimeDate = ctime((PLONG)&importDesc->TimeDateStamp);
        printf("  TimeDateStamp:   %08X", importDesc->TimeDateStamp);
        printf(pszTimeDate ? " -> %s" : "\n", pszTimeDate);

        printf("  ForwarderChain:  %08X\n", importDesc->ForwarderChain);
        printf("  First thunk RVA: %08X\n", importDesc->FirstThunk);

        thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)importDesc->Characteristics;
        thunkIAT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)importDesc->FirstThunk;

        if (thunk == 0)   // No Characteristics field?
        {
            // Yes! Gotta have a non-zero FirstThunk field then.
            thunk = thunkIAT;

            if (thunk == 0)   // No FirstThunk field?  Ooops!!!
                return;
        }

        // Adjust the pointer to point where the tables are in the
        // mem mapped file.
        thunk = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD)thunk, pNTHeader, base);
        if (!thunk)
            return;

        thunkIAT = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
            GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD)thunkIAT, pNTHeader, base);

        printf("  Ordn  Name\n");

        while (1) // Loop forever (or until we break out)
        {
            if (thunk->u1.AddressOfData == 0)
                break;

            if (thunk->u1.Ordinal & IMAGE_ORDINAL_FLAG)
            {
                printf("  %4u", IMAGE_ORDINAL(thunk->u1.Ordinal));
            }
            else
            {
                pOrdinalName = thunk->u1.AddressOfData;
                pOrdinalName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)
                    GetPtrFromRVA((DWORD)pOrdinalName, pNTHeader, base);

                printf("  %4u  %s", pOrdinalName->Hint, pOrdinalName->Name);
            }

            // If the user explicitly asked to see the IAT entries, or
            // if it looks like the image has been bound, append the address
            if (fShowIATentries || importDesc->TimeDateStamp)
                printf(" (Bound to: %08X)", thunkIAT->u1.Function);

            printf("\n");

            thunk++;            // Advance to next thunk
            thunkIAT++;         // advance to next thunk
        }

        importDesc++;   // advance to next IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Exiting\n");
}
```

The problem I am having is that on line  `if ((importDesc->TimeDateStamp == 0) && (importDesc->Name == 0))` in the `DumpImportsSection`, an `access violation 0xC0000005` exception is thrown. I am assuming the problem is on how I pass the `start` and `end` to `DumpImportsSection`, but don't know how can I resolve it. Can anyone assist?

Comment: Don't see where `size` was defined or initialized before calling `anPefile((unsigned char*)startAddress), size);`

Comment: @RetiredNinja let just say that `Size` is the size of pefile mapped in memory.

Comment: Let's just say your code is crashing and this example doesn't fill me with confidence that the value is correct.

Comment: You did a first sanity check of `importDesc` before the outer `while`, that's good. But in the loop, are you sure you can access all memory (the first and perhaps following structures) pointed to by `importDesc`? How many loop turns are successful before it crashes? -- BTW, why do you print _the address_ of `importDesc`? Don't you want to see its value?

Comment: @thebusybee, the loop is expected to run until the end of the descriptor (No more imports). The loop crashes on the first round. "why do you print the address of importDesc?", to find where import desk points to so I could manually trace the importDesc->Name value and why it crashes.

Comment: I see the reason, but wanted to be sure. `&importDesc` is the address where the pointer is stored, on the stack. It will be the same every turn of the loop. You surely want to print the value of `importDesc`, which is the pointer you use later, to check that it is not `NULL`.